# Get cell value based on current month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to set value for current row/cell based on other cell value.

Row with "c" is set as current month (`=IF(d1=TEXT(TODAY();"MMM");"c";"")`)

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1               c
2      JAN FEB MAR APR MAY
3       32  34  23  22  44
4  33   22  25  33  44  22
5       12  12  33  32  32
```

So, just below (per row) "Current Month" I would like to get the corresponding value in the cell where "c" is present in top row.

In image example, because the "c" is in D column, the number set is 33(value in D column, row 4)

Anyone - how would the formula in the cell "33" be?

Comment: This is typically an (H/V/X)LOOKUP task or INDEX/MATCH. If you have markdown sample data it's easier for people to help you out.

Comment: added data in another way - better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your monthnames are in a format similar to what `TEXT(TODAY();"MMM")` will give, you can put in something like `=XLOOKUP(TEXT(TODAY();"MMM");$B$3:$M$3;$B4:$M4;"no match")`.

If you look at [`XLOOKUP`'s documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929), you'll see that the first argument is the text to search for, the second the range to search, and the third the range to return a result from. The fourth argument is not strictly necessary, but is the return value if there is no match.

In the screenshot below, I've put `=TEXT(TODAY();"mmm")` in A3, and the formula `=XLOOKUP($A$3;$B$3:$M$3;$B4:$M4;"no match")` in the cell A4, and just copied it down.

The reason I put `=TEXT(TODAY();"mmm")` in a cell of its own, is that it's [a volatile function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation#volatile-and-non-volatile-functions), so I don't want it to appear in too many formulas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had a simple solution:

```
=IF($H$3="c";H6;IF($I$3="c";I6;IF($J$3="c";J6;IF($K$3="c";K6;IF($L$3="c";L6;IF($M$3="c";M6;IF($N$3="c";N6;IF($O$3="c";O6;IF($P$3="c";P6;IF($Q$3="c";Q6;IF($R$3="c";R6;IF($S$3="c";S6;"None"))))))))))))
```

A long and not so smart solution.. but still.. a solution ;)