# Will it be more efficient referencing a cell containing a volatile function than including the function in several formulas?

Tags: excel

When e.g. searching for the current month in a table, is it better to use a `TODAY()` function in a single cell to calculate the month, or is it just as efficient putting `TODAY()` in every formula which uses the current month.

The reason I'm asking is that while answering [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63937721/get-cell-value-based-on-current-month) earlier today, I recommended putting the current month (calculated based on `TODAY()`) into a single cell and reference this, instead of including it in every formula in the sheet. However, upon reading [the documentation on volatile functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation#volatile-and-non-volatile-functions), I came across the text

> Excel reevaluates cells that contain volatile functions, together with all dependents, every time that it recalculates.

Since all dependents are reevaluated anyway, does it matter whether `TODAY()` is in another cell or in the dependent formula?

Comment: Consider what happens when a volatile function takes a long time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a little experiment, because I've always wondered this too.

I created a spreadsheet with 200,000 x 100 cells with `=TODAY()` inside them.

From VBA, I executed `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`, and then `Application.Calculate`

Interestingly, Excel was very slow grinding through that second calculate instruction, even though the dependency tree had been fully rebuilt.

I ran a second experiment, this time populating every cell with `=NOW()`, and I repeated the process.

The results were even more surprising!

Firstly, the first and last cells had different values

Then I changed the format to `ss`, so I would only see the seconds component.

Each cell had a different result! Excel did not appear to be solving each instance of `=NOW()` by working left-right and top-down, but appeared to be solving some other way.

[Picture of Calculation Experiment: Top-left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2AZv.jpg)

[Picture of Calculation Experiment: Bottom-right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN74r.jpg)

While the cells tended to have a similar (but not the same) answer when they were close together, the further two cells were apart, the more different their results were!

"Common sense" would suggest that Excel would only solve volatile functions once per `Calculate()` command, grouped by inputs, but this is not the case. Instead, every single call to a volatile command has it recalculated afresh.